# cs-bytes and sc-bytes in Wowza/FMS

Tags: wowza, flash-media-server, adobe-media-server

What is the meaning for both cs-bytes and sc-bytes from Wowza/FMS access log ?. In my log, its show cs-bytes-->1756310375  and sc-bytes--->3492. I couldn't understand anything from these value.

Someone please share the detail info behind this

My sample Log file:

2015-07-20 20:28:22 UTC connect session INFO 200 10.11.12.13 - *defaultVHost* live *definst* 0.013 [any] 1935 rtmp://10.11.12.122:1935/live/ 10.11.12.13 rtmp https://test.example.com/video.swf LNX 15,0,0,189 1756310375 3492 3073 - - - - - - - - - - - - - rtmp://10.11.12.122:1935/live/ -

Answer (score 0):

Generally in logs such as this, any field prefixed `cs-` indicates information that was sent from the `c`lient to the `s`server.

Any field prefixed `sc-` indicates information sent from the `s`erver to the `c`lient.

So, in your case, the client set 1514823450 bytes to the server and the server sent 3615 bytes to the client.

The common prefixes can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-logfile.html):

```
c
Client
s
Server
r
Remote
cs
Client to Server.
sc
Server to Client.
sr
Server to Remote Server, this prefix is used by proxies.
rs
Remote Server to Server, this prefix is used by proxies.
x
Application specific identifier.
```

Comment: From the documentation itself, I can understand the description behind it. But from where this much bytes value comes ?.

Comment: @KMG - they came from the client. *why* the client chose to send so much data and *how* the server reacted to it are information I cannot tell you - since the former requires us to know what the specific client was (and possibly to see how else it had interacted with the server recently), and the latter would require you to at least give us the *complete* line of logging information.

Comment: Sample logs ,
2015-07-20 20:28:22 UTC connect session INFO 200 10.11.12.13 - _defaultVHost_ live _definst_ 0.013 [any] 1935 rtmp://10.11.12.122:1935/live/ 10.11.12.13 rtmp https://test.example.com/video.swf LNX 15,0,0,189 1756310375 3492 3073 - - - - - - - - - - - - - rtmp://10.11.12.122:1935/live/ -

======
here you could see , after clientID the value is "1756310375" cs-bytes. I'm not sure from where this value comes and in what basis they are mentioning in log file ?

Comment: Please *edit* your question to add that information. In questions (and answers) you can use tools like `{}` to present tabular data. In comments... not so much.

Comment: I have added it. Pls share your idea on this. that would help me for further proceeding.

Comment: @damien-the-unbeliever  - any chance to check this ?